# How do I avoid calling my initialization method repeatedly in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, performance, initialization, pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) { // sadly, **never** in here   }

    MyInit() // Slow initialization method, that I only wan't to call one time.
}
```

So, if I can't tuck my `MyInit()` in the `if`, can I solve my performance/strucktur problem with use of `OnNeedDataSource()`?

Comment: So is MyInit a static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if this is what you mean, but to initialise something once from Page_Load, you could use a static class with a static bool to determine if it's been initialized.  Given it's on Page_Load, you'll also need to guard against multiple threads - so use a double checked lock to make it threadsafe and guard against a race condition.

```
public static class InitMe
{
    private static bool isInitialized = false;
    private static object theLock = new Object();

    public static void MyInit()
    {
        if(!isInitialized)
        {
            lock(theLock);
            {
                if(!isInitialized)    // double checked lock for thread safety
                {
                    // Perform initialization
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in your Page_Load, call it via `InitMe.MyInit()`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks very interesting, i'm gonna give it a try for sure.

Comment: I can't perform my initialization, because i'm in a static method. I'm trying to modify your example a bit, but i don't know how good it will be then.

Comment: Can you turn it into a singleton?

Comment: Yes, i did that. But there is still a problem. Because the page is a page from my big left menu.. So when i press another menupage, and then return to this page, it has to do the initialization again. So i guess, i need to set `isInitialized ` to false again, when i move to another menupage right?

Comment: But still, maybe `OnNeedDataSource()` is the right way to go.

Comment: Ahh - so you need it to initialise once *per page* - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnLoad(e);

   if (!Page.IsPostBack) { MyInit(); }
}
```

I assume you are in a page or user control...

HTH.

Comment: IsPostBack is also always true here, so I won't work, unless i missed something?

Comment: I never had an issue with !Page.IsPostBack on the first page load; this should be being called the first page load...  Maybe there is some custom plumbing here that we need to know about?  Also, could you post a larger code sample?

Comment: Okay i might have make a sample, because it's not just a simple stand-a-lone page. the page is from a menu.
I read something somewhere on SO, about a page calling it self will always have it's IsPostBack true.